# HTML/Javascript: Get X, Y Coordinates of Circle Element

Tags: html, javascript

I need to get the X and Y coordinates of an HTML circle element in Javascript. Here's my HTML code:

```
    <svg id="hotspot_canvas" name="hotspot_canvas" class="hotspot" width="800" height="1570.66666667" style="background-image: url('images/characters/fullbody/1.jpg'); background-size: 800px 1570.66666667px;">
        <circle class="hotspot" id="hotspot0" name="hotspot0" cx="300" cy="75" r="50" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="MovePopup('0', 200, 200);" onmouseover="MovePopup('0', 200, 200);" onmouseout="MovePopup('0', 200, -1000)" alt="" />
    </svg>
```

In my MovePopup Javascript subroutine, I have this code:

```
function MovePopup(id, xcoord, ycoord) {
    var hotspot = document.getElementById('hotspot' + id);
    window.alert('Hotspot is ' + hotspot.style.left + ' pixels from the left of the window');
}
```

What I need is to get the number of pixels from the left of the entire window (not just the SVG element), but everything I try gives me either 'undefined' or nothing. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try using hotspot.cx and hotspot.cy. now add position of the canvas element to get the potion relative to window.